# variance unchanged under subtracting mean - application in portfolio theory

Tags: probability, finance, actuarial-science

I’m working through the following passage:

> We will be interested in the variance of the portfolio returns given the variances of individual asset’s returns. If we have assets with returns $R_1,\ldots,R_n$, held in amounts $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ then we can compute the variance of the portfolio.
>   $\newcommand{\myVar}{\operatorname{Var}}$
>
> We proceed by direct computation. We seek the value of
>   $$\myVar(R_P) = \myVar\left( \sum_{i=1}^n X_i R_i \right).$$
>   We compute
>   $$
> \begin{align*}
> \myVar\left( \sum_{i=1}^n X_i R_i \right)
> &= \myVar\left( \sum_{i=1}^n X_i (R_i - \mathbb E(R_i)) \right), \\
> &= \mathbb E \left[\left( \sum_{j=1}^n X_j (R_j - E(R_j)) \right)^2\right], \\
> &= \mathbb E\left( \sum_{i=1}^n X_i (R_i - \mathbb E(R_i)) \sum_{j=1}^n X_j (R_j - \mathbb E(R_j)) \right), \\
> &= \sum_{i,j=1}^n X_i X_j\,\mathbb E(((R_i - \mathbb E(R_i))(R_j - \mathbb E(R_j))).
> \end{align*}
> $$
>   How do we even get the first step?

Comment: is it me or is loading the images taking ages?

Comment: @Lost1 - No, open both image in new tab

Comment: yeah, and it is taking ages to load. might be my computer... i dunno, anyway, i have an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line is always true. it is a basic property of variances.

Note  $X_i$ are fixed amount assets you wish to hold - i.e.constants

For any random variables $X,Y$, note $Cov(X,Y) = E(X-EX)E(Y-EY)=EX'EY'$, so where $X' = X-EX$ and $Y'=Y-EY$.

Now note $Cov(X',Y') = E(X'-EX')E(Y'-EY')=EX'EY'$, this is because $EX' = EX-E(EX) = 0$ and $EY'=0$

so we have

$Cov(X,Y) = Cov(X-EX, Y-EY)$  (1)

LHS of FIRST LINE = $\sum\limits_{i=1,j=1}^n X_iX_jCov(R_i,R_j)=\sum\limits_{i=1,j=1}^n X_iX_jCov(R_i-ER_i,R_j-ER_j)$ = RHS of FIRST LINE

where the equality in the middle used (1)

Comment: Could you show me which property is for the first line, thank you.